# Count unique users in groups and nested

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

I hope you guys can direct me where should I start.

We have Group A and B and nested group in Group B.

John is member to Group A and is in Australia 1 OU.
Chris is member to Group B and is in Australia 2 OU.
May is member to Group A and B and is in Australia 1 OU.
Ken is  member of Group A and is in China OU.

Australia 1 and Australia 2 are a subOU of Australia.

I need to find the unique user in both A and B group and need PowerShell to shown result as below.

```
OU             User Count in A and B Group
Australia 1      2
Australia 2      1
Other            1
```

I tired using the code below and it seem to work but how can I just get unique users and outout shown the NAME of OU instead showing DC.net\ABC\OU\User ?

```
$Group2 = ($Group_A, $Group_B)
$group2 | foreach-object {Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "$_" -Recursive } | 
Where-Object{$_.objectClass -eq "User"} |
Get-ADUser -Properties canonicalname | 
Select-Object @{Name='Container';Expression={$_.canonicalname | split-path -
parent}} |
Group-Object container |
Select Name,Count
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617195.aspx) is usually a pretty good starting point.

Comment: How can John be in 2 different OUs? Are they 2 different Johns?

Comment: I amended to Ken. thank